# Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1): AWS SNS Platform Application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm currently using FCM (legacy) to send push notifications to my customers' Android devices from AWS SNS by adding FCM as a platform endpoint.

I've recently received notification from Firebase that I need to update my application to the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging API, and migrate away from the legacy HTTP protocol to HTTP v1.

However, when trying to create a new / replacement Platform Application in AWS SNS console, I have to provide a server key - but I understand that server keys are only available for the legacy API.

Can anyone help me understand the protocol and process for migrating my existing AWS SNS to FCM platform integration to the new API, so that I can continue to send app notifications to my Android customers via AWS SNS once the FCM legacy HTTP protocol is deprecated?

Answer (score 8):

#### **UPDATE January 2024:**

Amazon SNS now supports Google FCM v1 API. It is now possible to create AWS SNS Android mobile push notifications via FCM v1 API when creating new SNS platform application. You can also upgrade your existing applications with a single call to the Amazon SNS `SetPlatformApplicationAttributes` API action.

AWS announcement regarding this update: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/01/amazon-sns-fcm-http-v1-api-mobile-notifications/

**Original answer:**

At the moment AWS SNS does not support Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1). The old API should work until 20/06/2024. Since 20/06/2023 Google also deprecated legacy API and you cannot use it for new apps anymore.
AWS teams are aware of this but we are still waiting for an update when they will integrate SNS with new FCM API as per this post:

https://repost.aws/questions/QUWxZXuxT3ShOrBGsTM0s9Ew/sns-uses-which-version-of-firebase-cloud-messaging-api

At the moment what you can do is:

1. Leave your platform running on legacy until  20/06/2024 and hope in the meantime AWS teams will implements new FCM APIv1 into SNS.
2. Create your own solution by omitting SNS completely and use FCM Admin SDK
   or HTTP REST APIv1 on your custom server environment to push notifications to Android devices. More documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: I'm bookmarking this answer.  Please, let us know as soon as AWS adds support for FCM API (V1).  Thank you.

Comment: Note that Apple/iOS support over FCM v1 is coming on 15th/March/2024:  "Amazon SNS now supports Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) HTTP V1 API for sending mobile push notifications to Android devices. Beginning March 15, 2024, Amazon SNS will introduce support for sending notifications to Apple devices" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html#mobile-push-send-platform

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2024, Amazon SNS now supports FCM v1 API, and with it, a token-based security model. Thus, if you have any mobile applications that deliver mobile push notifications via Amazon SNS to FCM, you can now upgrade your applications in place, with a single call to the Amazon SNS `SetPlatformApplicationAttributes` API action.

More info about this feature announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2024/01/amazon-sns-fcm-http-v1-api-mobile-notifications/